# How to fix missing right parenthesis in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting a right parenthesis issue while solving this problem:
List out driver name, age,position,average trip rating for this particular month: April

this is what I have tried in my sql.

```
CREATE TABLE driver (
    driverID NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY, 
    Dname VARCHAR2(20),
    DNRIC CHAR(14),
    Dgender CHAR(1),
    DDOB DATE,
    Dmobile CHAR(11),
    DcarNo CHAR(6),
    Dstart DATE,
    Dstop DATE,
    Dgrade CHAR(6),
    DLicence CHAR(4)
 );


CREATE TABLE booking (
    BookID NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    PID NUMBER(4),
    driverID NUMBER(4),    
       PickLoc VARCHAR2(13),
       DropLoc VARCHAR2(13),
       TDate DATE,
       TTime NUMBER(4),
       RideFare CHAR(6),
       TollOther CHAR(6),
    cancelDate DATE,
       TripRating NUMBER(1), 
    PayMethod CHAR(15),
 FOREIGN KEY (PID) references passenger (PID),
 FOREIGN KEY (driverID) references driver (driverID)
 );



 SELECT Dname as driver, 
 floor(months_between(sysdate,driver.DDOB)/12) as age,
 Dgrade as position,
 rating
 FROM driver
 LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT driverID, avg(TripRating) as rating
 FROM booking group by driverID
 where (TDate between '01-Apr-2019' and '30-Apr-2019')
 order by rating) 
 booking on driver.driverID = booking.bookingID
```

missing right parenthesis. Besides, I would like to get average rating for the driver in April

Comment: There is no varchar2 or number datatype in mysql so is this purely and oracle question or are you trying to convert oracle to mysql?

Comment: A group by has to appear after a where statement in a query.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't allow using an `order by` clause in such a subquery (since it would be meaningless anyway), and gives a pretty annoying counter-intuitive ORA-00907 error when you try. Moving the `order by` clause should do the trick. Also, note that the `where` clause should come before the `group by` clause, not after it:

```
SELECT     dname AS driver, 
           FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, driver.ddob) / 12) AS age,
           dgrade AS position,
           rating
FROM       driver
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   driverid,
                    AVG(triprating) AS rating
           FROM     booking
           WHERE    tdate BETWEEN '01-Apr-2019' AND '30-Apr-2019'
           GROUP BY driverid) booking ON driver.driverid = booking.driverid
ORDER BY  rating -- Moved here
```

Comment: there is an invalid identifier on booking.bookingid :(

Comment: @ShuYi arg, should have been `driverid`, mea culpa. (edited and fixed)

Comment: "BOOKING"."DRIVERID": invalid identifier